# GWT + Spring: Возможно ли их подружить на клиенте?

Tags: spring, gwt

Добрый день. Добавил в своё GWT-приложение поддержку Spring. И обломался.
Компилятор ругается страшно:

```
 No source code is available for type org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext; did you forget to inherit a required module?
 No source code is available for type org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Быстрый "гуглёж", принёс понимание того, что на клиенте Spring реализовать нельзя?! Весь проект стоит под ударом, если чего-нибудь не придумаю на эту тему.

Народ, подскажите (а лучше киньте ссылкой на )примеры, где выходят из такого положения :(

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Spring в GWT напрямую использовать нельзя. Как и большинство других библиотек, о которых специально не позаботились.

Например, откуда на клиенте возьмется `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, если конечный исполняемый артефакт - JavaScript в браузере. Там нет ни CLASSPATH, ни понятия о вашем Spring-контексте.

Выход - грамотно проектировать приложение, разделять обязанности клиента и сервера.

---

PS. Если вам просто нужен Dependency Injection на клиенте - это уже другой вопрос. Можете попробовать Gin/Guice.

Comment: Если честно, то у меня задание такое: написать приложение с исп. фреймворка gwt + hibernate + spring. Если первые два я подружил при помощи rpc-вызовов, то с последним застрял.

Comment: Просто не используйте спринг на клиенте. Пусть он занимается только сервером.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как его на сервере использовать? У меня к примеру были планы на spring IoC но раз с клиентом облом... На сервере использовать ioc нет смысла?

Comment: Почему нет. Более чем есть. Посмотрите любой пример про Hibernate+Spring.

Comment: Как я понял, любой не подойдет. Нужно именно GWT + Spring + Hibernate. Т.к. основная "грабля" именно в GWT таится, т.к. на клиенте нельзя сделать Spring IoC как раз из-за GWT.

Comment: Нет никаких граблей. Вас же не беспокоит, что Hibernate не работает на клиенте.

Comment: Делаете на GWT клиент, на Spring + Hibernate - сервер. Для стимулирования более активного использования Spring-а, можете, например, отказаться от GWT-RPC для обмена данными и использовать голый HTTP. На стороне сервера, соответственно у вас будут веб-сервисы на Spring MVC: [`@Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html), [`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) - вот это все.

Answer (score 1):

у тебя вот такая схема
GWT <-> Spring <-> (Hibernate/JDBCTemplate/etc)

связка GWT <-> Spring транспорт можно на JSON делать. Для этого есть AutoBean (интерфейсы для каждого типа сообщения) либо OverlyTypes (экстендить JavaScriptObject для каждого типа сообщения)

Самое интересное это структура проекта: в нем должны быть два модуля - web и server. Во время разработки запускаете (пример для мавен проекта) две разные сборки мавена:

1. в web - gwt:run
2. в server - spring-boot:run

*Моя проблема сейчас: как потом сделать единый war этих двух модулей.*